# Multiply each channel pixel with given vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, math

Basically i want to multiply each channnel value of image with vector . For example Vec4f(1,2,3,4)  1 * Red channel of image 2 * Green channel and so on Here is my code(not a complete code and has some errors) but my boss says there must be better and simple way with opencv but i couldnt find out. Thank in advance.

```
      void scaleImage(TextureData& dst, TextureData const& src, cv::Vec4f 
      const& scale)
      {


auto size = src.info.size;
dst=src;
cv::Mat bgr[4];
cv::split(src.levels[0].images[0], bgr);

for (int y = 0; y < size.height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size.width; ++x)
    {

        src.levels[0].images[0].channels();

        if (src.levels[0].images[0].channels() == 4)
        {
            auto& imgRGB = dst.levels[0].images[0].at<cv::Vec4f>(x, y);
            imgRGB[3] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.w()*bgr[3].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.x()*bgr[2].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.y()*bgr[1].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.z()*bgr[0].at[x, y]);

        }

        if (src.levels[0].images[0].channels() == 3)
        {
            auto& imgRGB = dst.levels[0].images[0].at<cv::Vec3f>(x, y);
            imgRGB[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.x()*bgr[2].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.y()*bgr[1].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.z()*bgr[0].at[x, y]);
        }

        if (src.levels[0].images[0].channels() == 2)
        {
            auto& imgRGB = dst.levels[0].images[0].at<cv::Vec2f>(x, y);
            imgRGB[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.x()*bgr[2].at[x, y]);
            imgRGB[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.y()*bgr[1].at[x, y]);
        }

        if (src.levels[0].images[0].channels() == 2)
        {
            auto& imgRGB = dst.levels[0].images[0].at<float>(x, y);
            imgRGB[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(scale.x()*bgr[2].at[x, y]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Antonio but Mat*scalar gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it is a little bit strange problem. I dont think anyone needs this function but in case... be cause it costs me 2-3 days(just 25 lines)

```
  void scaleImage(TextureData& dst, TextureData const& src, Vec4f const& 
  scale)
  {    
   std::vector<cv::Mat> bgr(3);
   std::vector<cv::Mat> resultMask(3);
   src.info;

  cv::split(src.levels[0].images[0], bgr);
  //dst = src;
  //auto size = src.info.size;

   cv::Point anchor = cv::Point(-1, -1);

        float a = scale.x();
        float b = scale.y();
        float c = scale.z();
        float d = scale.w();
        cv::Mat kern = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                                 0, a, 0,
                                                 0, 0, 0);
        cv::Mat kern1 = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                                 0, b, 0,
                                                 0, 0, 0);
        cv::Mat kern2 = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                                 0, c, 0,
                                                 0, 0, 0);
        cv::Mat kern3 = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 0, 0,
                                                 0, d, 0,
                                                 0, 0, 0);
        cv::filter2D(bgr[0], resultMask[0], bgr[0].depth(), kern,  anchor, 0, 1);
        cv::filter2D(bgr[1], resultMask[1], bgr[1].depth(), kern1, anchor, 0, 1);
        cv::filter2D(bgr[2], resultMask[2], bgr[2].depth(), kern2, anchor, 0, 1);
        //cv::filter2D(bgr[3], resultMask[3], bgr[3].depth(), kern3, anchor, 0, 1);

        cv::merge(resultMask, dst.levels[0].images[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure what you like to do, but thought about cv::multiply ?

- wich version of opencv do you use?
- is it a const factor or const matrix of factors?

Comment: Just a nested class.. const source. Mat is in TextureData class(basically source is a Mat). I use last version of opencv